# Very messy prints with lots of fuzz on edges

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-failure

Recently my prints come out very messy. I tightened everything up and checked the extrusion multiplier.

I have an Ender 3 Pro which I use together with Cura 4.2.1 (and Octoprint). I print in PLA at 190°C. The print bed is set to 70°C. The Bed temperature is lower though, since I use a glas bed on top of the heated bed. I use a print cooling fan at 100%. The layer height is set to 0.2 mm, the line width 0.4mm from the 0.4mm nozzle. My retraction is 5mm at 45mm/s.

Does anyone have any idea what the reason could be?

[image]

Comment: Hello Chry007. Your question is very terse and hard to answer without knowing a couple of things about your printer setup. Please [edit] and fill in the [placeholders] in the template I added and then remove the leading < afterward. This will turn it visible and help us help you find the actual problem.

Comment: Are the walls very sparse/porous/brittle? It looks to me like you might have severe underextrusion from filament diameter being set to 2.85 or 3 rather than 1.75 (a common problem with Cura).

Comment: Hi R., not at all. I can' break the model with my hands. I just doublechecked the settings in Cura and it's set to 1.75mm

Comment: @Chry007 speed retraction is too low, the amount of retraction is too high...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I reduced printing speed and printing temperature and the print came out decent. Still some issues but worlds better then before. I will try a few more settings to determine exactly what was the actual Issue. I will also try what @Fernando Baltazar recommended and update here what exactly changed the printing quality.

[image]

Comment: "Retraction amount is too high" is not a thing unless you have increased it to some extreme amount or have a specialized hotend. Lower than 5 mm is definitely bad.

Comment: I can confirm. I tried with 3.5mm and the only result was more stringing.

Comment: what speed and temp did you end up going with?